# How to open a folder in a new tab in Alfresco using AJAX?

Tags: alfresco, yui, alfresco-share

I have `View Policy` button in my `custom-toolbar.js`. When I click the button it has to open the `Policy` folder in a new tab. This is what I have done so far.

```
    /**
     * View Policy button click handler  
     * 
     * @method onViewDocument
     * @param e {object} DomEvent
     * 
     */
    onViewPolicy: function DLTB_onViewPolicy(e, p_obj)
    {                   
        var newPath = this.currentPath + "/Policy",

        filter = this.currentFilter;
        filter.filterData = newPath;
        // Refresh the Document Library
        YAHOO.Bubbling.fire("changeFilter", filter);

    }
```

This opens the folder in the same tab. How can I use Alfresco.util.Ajax.request in this situation and make it open in a new tab? Also is it possible to display an error message if Policy folder does not return anything?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to open the path in new tab, you just need to do is use `window.open(url);`.

If you want to do a validation by calling a webscript, you can use `Alfresco.util.Ajax.request`.

Sample code:

```
 Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({
                type: "GET",
                url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI.replace('share/proxy/alfresco', 'alfresco/service') + {webscript url},
                dataType: 'text',
                headers: {
                    Accept: "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET"
                },
                successCallback: {
                    fn: function(response) {
            //collect the output.
            //if json
            output = JSON.parse(response.serverResponse.responseText);
            var result =output["result"];
            //if html is the output
            output = (response.serverResponse.responseText);
            var result =/<body.*?>([\s\S]*)<\/body>/.exec(output)[1];//to get contents inside body tag
            if(result says folder is present)
            {
            window.open(newurl);
            }
            else
            {
            //show error popup.
            }
                    },
                    scope: this
                },
                failureMessage: "",
                execScripts: true
            });
```

Comment: I cannot directly assign the newPath to the url and unless I do filter change it returns me a 404. How should I go about it? I'm a newbie to Alfresco.

Comment: I cannot directly assign the newPath to the url and unless I do filter change it returns me a 404. How should I go about it? I'm a newbie to Alfresco.

Comment: @BlueStar : Am also a beginner. I can give a workaround to solve your problem. Please try the below to get the url
`url =window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf("&")-3)+"%2FPolicy%7C&page=1";`